# Twython - How can I get a list of users I have unfollowed?

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I have two Twython apps - one that follows users based on certain criteria, and another one that unfollows users if they don't follow me. I want to get a list of the users I have unfollowed so that the first bot doesn't try to follow them again! Is there a way to do this? Apologies if this is very simple, I'm fairly new to coding in general!

```
unfollowed = [""]
twitter = Twython(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, 
                  access_token_secret)
following = twitter.get_friends_ids(screen_name = "Example", count =  500)['ids']
followers = twitter.get_followers_ids(screen_name = "Example", count = 500)['ids']
for user in following:
    if user in followers:
        continue
    else:
        twitter.destroy_friendship(id = user)
        unfollowed.append(user)
```

The problem I'm having is that every time I run this, it obviously deletes anything that was in "unfollowed".

Comment: Hello. Could you please show us some of the code you have written? That will make it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I edited my question to include some of my code, hopefully this clears things up a little!

Answer (score 1):

There's no trick to this.  Neither Twitter nor Twython will tell you someone you used to follow, so you have to maintain that data yourself.

Right where you have unfollowed.append(user) make sure you're saving your unfollowed list into nonvolatile storage so you can compare them to your list of who to follow.

If you're running locally sqlite or csv would be a simple way to keep track. If you're working on a website then MySQL, Mongo or some other storage system would work.